# Quick Launch Flyout Width

Tags: quick-launch

On my root level site I currently have flyouts that are not appropriately sized for the links within them.  I need to adjust the width of these flyouts so that the links within are not dropped to another line.

[image]

I am unsure the process of adjusting the width of these, any detailed advice would be appreciated.

Here is the code I am attempting to use with no luck, I may be way off...

```
<style>#v4quicklaunchmenu .menu-item { width:150px; } #sideNavBox ul.dynamic </style>
```

Comment: Anyone have any suggestions on this?

Answer (score 0):

What I did was add an alternate site CSS so that even all subsites would inherit it.  Here is the code:

```
<style type="text/css">ul.dynamic {width:185px;}</style>
```

Even though this didn't specifically target each dropdown or flyout, it made everything uniform.

If anyone has a different route to take or one that may be more preferred for myself or others, please share.